Using differential scores instead of the interaction term as the "IV" for mediation (lmer)
I’m planning to do a mediation analysis using the mediation package in R.
There are two groups of participants in my experiment (categorical IV group, between subject, two levels) completing a task where they are supposed to rate e.g the distress level (DV) of 2 different conditions (categorical IV condition, within subject, two levels) . This is my main model testing group * condition interaction
lmer(DV ~ cond*group + (1|ID))

I would like to test the mediation effect of an another variable (M), to see whether this interaction disappears / reduced when it is added to the overall equation. Now I am a bit puzzled.
For Mediation, I believe that I need to calculate these models:
Model1 <- Total effect model: lmer(DV ~ cond*group + (1|ID))
Model2 <- Model testing the effect of the IV onto the mediator: lmer(M ~ cond*group + (1|ID))
Model 3 <- Model testing the mediator on the DV while controlling for the IV:  lmer(DV ~ M + cond*group + (1¬|ID))

And I’d then run the mediation analysis
mediate(model2, model3, treat='(?)', mediator='M', boot=T)

So here I put (?) in treat variable because, I don't know how can I incorporate the interaction term there (cond*group)? An another issue is that, M is a variable that is measured after the experiment. It is measured for the two groups, yes, but it is not separated by “cond” variable, so to say. So if I run this model, on my table, M scores will be the same for both levels of cond obviously. So, I am not sure doing it like this makes sense? I thought of these:

Using the first formula(s), if in Model 3, the interaction effect is reduced or gone (as compared to Model 1), would that also be enough evidence for mediation (assuming also a significant effect is found on Model2) ? So can I prove mediation without running the mediation function?

Can I maybe use differential scores of my DV based on "cond"? (i.e. substracting two levels) and run the analysis with the “group” being the only IV? Because I am actually interested in this differentiation between the conditions anyway. So, then I would no longer use lmer but lm instead:


Model1 <- Total effect model: lm(DV(differential) ~ group)
Model2 <- Model testing the effect of the IV onto the mediator: lm(M ~ group)
Model 3 <- Model testing the mediator on the DV while controlling for the IV:  lm(DV(differential)~ M + group)

Would that be problematic? If so, is there any alternative ways?

What is the reason you are using a mixed model in the first place? Are there repeated measures by subject?

Yes indeed, every subject encounter two conditions, hence the (1|ID). So it is necessary for my main model. But maybe not so much for the mediation?
